# Creating an interactive shell for a command

Tags: bash

I have a server running an application (puppet) and administration of the server is done almost exclusively with that programs specific commands.

It would be neat to configure the server like a dedicated appliance similar to how a Cisco IOS works with the puppet command.

The puppet command has many arguments many of which also requires elevation so im frequently typing "sudo puppet command subcommand subcommand argument".

I want to be able to type "sudo puppet" and then enter the "puppet" context where I only have to type the top level commands without having to type "sudo puppet command".

Then after I enter the command and I'm in the commands context and I only have to enter the sub command and argument to the subcommand.

Is it clear what I'm trying to accomplish? Is this possible?

Comment: You could use something like `read variable && puppet $variable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually fairly easy to accomplish, you can use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
    echo -n "puppet> "
    read input
    puppet $input
done
```

Save with a name like `foo.sh`, then just run `sudo bash foo.sh` (or `sudo ./foo.sh` if you set the executable flag).